# how to get checkbox text in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="Checkbox" value="1">Option1</input>
```

How to get text value ?

I need to get option1 text .

Comment: The correct syntax would be `<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox1" /> <label for="checkbox1">Option1</label>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, `input` tag doesn't have a closing tag, it's a self close tag, so what you are doing is completely WRONG.

This is the valid way to go for

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Side Note : Ignore using uppercase, though it won't mess up your document but it's a good practice to ignore using uppercase.

---

Lastly to get the text of the `value`, you can use `.attr()` method

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    //or
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZwB6/)

Answer (score 0):

htlm

```
<input id="check-box" type="Checkbox" value="1">Option1</input>
```

js

```
var text = $("#check-box")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

Comment: You need to read my answer..

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this create a custom attribute like this :-

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="mycheckbox" data-checkbox-text="Option1">Option1
```

using jQuery

```
var name = $('#mycheckbox').attr('checkbox-text');
```

Comment: Not the down voter but the attribute here is invalid too, if you want to declare your own attribute you need to use `data-` before the name, which is valid in HTML5